# Reference for a special case of the Hanson-Wright inequality

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

I would like find tail bounds for the expression
$$
\begin{align*}
\left|\left\langle a,\phi\right\rangle \left\langle \phi,b\right\rangle -\left\langle a,b\right\rangle\right|,
\end{align*}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are fixed **complex** vectors and $\phi$ is a vector with iid Rademacher entries.
I know that this is a special case of *Hanson-Wright inequality*, but I couldn't find any reference that explicitly considers complex matrices. I hesitate to derive the desired bound using the real version, because I would like to obtain reasonably sharp constant factors.

**Question:** Can anyone point me to a reference that directly addresses complex Hanson-Wright inequality, or at least my special case?